# import loopback repository of one controller to another controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, loopback, loopback4

in test.controller.ts file

```
import {repository} from '@loopback/repository';
import {ProductRepository} from '../repositories';
export class TestController {
constructor(
    @repository(ProductRepository)
    public productRepository: ProductRepository,
  ) { }

static async createData(data:any){
  await this.productRepository.updatedById(11, {'code': 'asd1232d'});
  return true;
}

}
```

gives me an error in vs code
Property 'productRepository' does not exist on type 'typeof TestController'.

Answer (score 1):

Your `createData()` is `static` you can't call an instance injected via your constructor in a static method.